# Converting infix expression to RPN using Shunting Yard Algorithm

Tags: infix-notation, rpn, shunting-yard

I have been trying to correctly answer a past exam paper question which asks me to convert 5+3*6*(8*2+1) to RPN. The only answer I get is 53682***1+.

When I evaluate my above RPN answer, I do not get the expected answer of 311. I would be extremely grateful if some one could tell me how to answer this ie. which RPN answer should I get? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possible RPN notation structures that work, but one is as follows:

```
82*1+63**5+
```

or

```
53682*1+**+
```

A basic sanity check is do the operators exist in the same order that you would execute based on the order of operations in algebraic notation?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For your 53682*1+**+ answer, is it possible to explain how you got the answer after the 53682? I just can't seem to get that order for some reason

Comment: Ohh actually I have it now! When I reach the second +, I just pop the * off the top of the stack into the queue, keeping the (, *, * and + on the stack (top to bottom), then put the second + on the top of the stack, then the 1 in the queue. Then, once I get to the ) I pop everything off the stack into the queue? This gives me your second answer. Thanks